# How to convert an array of objects, into an object of the same objects in JS?

Tags: javascript, json

I have array of objects, and I need to convert this array:

```
data = [
  {
   propertyName: value1,
   propertyName2: value2 
  },
  {
   propertyName: value3,
   propertyName2: value4 
  }
]
```

So it looks like this this:

```
data = {
      {
       propertyName: value1,
       propertyName2: value2 
      },
      {
       propertyName: value3,
       propertyName2: value4 
      }
    }
```

What's the best and the most efficient way of doing it? Thanks!

Comment: Objects ***need*** to have a property like this: `{property: value}`. What you expect is impossible, unless you tell us what properties you want.

Comment: Without Key, you can not set value. This is programmatically wrong.If you need {key: value} then please refer below code:
var jsonObj = {};
for (var i = 0 ; i < data.length; i++) {
    jsonObj[(i+1)] = data[i];
}